# Verb Conjugation using "keiner von beiden"

Tags: pronoun, conjugation

When you conjugate a verb for use with the pronoun `beide`, you use the 3. Plural.

`Beide brauchen geld`

But what happens in case we use `keiner von beiden` instead?

I did a google exact text search, and I found a lot of examples using the 1. Singular, but also 3. Singular.

---

**Some Examples found:**

- `Keiner von beiden muss schnaufen.`
- `Ich denke, keiner von beiden braucht dieses Zimmer.`
- `Keiner von beiden hat recht.`

---

I find it hard to locate examples with `keiner von beiden` used with the 3. Plural, so I believe it is used with either the 1. Singular or 3. Singular but I have not yet been able to track down some information on the topic about it.

So to compare two examples of usage I found on the internet against how I would write it:

- `Ich denke, keiner von beiden braucht dieses Zimmer.`
- `Keiner von beiden muss schnaufen.`
  Versus
- `Ich denke, keiner von beiden brauchen dieses Zimmer.`
- `Keiner von beiden müssen schnaufen.`

What is the correct conjugation when using `keiner von beiden`?

Comment: The simple answer is that the verb refers to "keiner", 3rd person, and "von beiden" is just the narrowing of the set!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pronoun "kein-" as a subject is always treated as singular 3. person, never plural and never 1. or 2. person.

This doesn't change for "keiner/keine/keines von beiden", which is not different from English "none of both *is*" (although it is "none of *them are*" for some reason none of us understands, or understand)

However, when "kein" is used attributively as a determiner of a noun in the subject, the verb is of course conjugated in agreement with the number of the noun:

```
In diese Kneipe gehen keine Touristen.
In diese Kneipe geht kein Tourist.
```

Answer (score 2):

*Keiner* is the 3. person singular:

> **Keiner** von <s>ihnen/</s> beiden **hat** ...

It is the same in English:

> **No one** of both **has** ... <s>**None** of them **has** ...</s>

Answer (score -1):

**Kein** isn't a verb, so it isn't conjugated but **declined**. That is why things like "1st person" or "3rd person" don't make sense at all.

The tricky thing which may have confused you is articles (and *kein* follows this pattern) exist in all genders. (It seems to confuse English speakers to think that is "because of 3rd person singular", as it's the only place where English makes a difference between genders.)

```
           Einzahl                 Mehrzahl
           m       w       s
Nominativ  keiner  keine   kein    keine
Genitiv    keines  keiner  keines  keiner 
Dativ      keinem  keiner  keinem  keinen
Akkusativ  keinen  keine   kein    keine
```

---

So, your question has to be rephrased. I think it boils down to singular vs. plural. If you can speak English, this isn't scary at all.

> Beide brauchen Geld.

*Both need money.*

Obviously these are two entities, because of *beide*. So the verb has to be in plural. As in English.

> Keiner braucht Geld.

*No one needs money.*

It's *no one*. Singular. As in English.

Now a tricky example:

> Keiner von beiden braucht Geld.

*Neither of both needs money.*

Tricky? **No**, it's the same as in English. Singular.

> Hier sind keine Leute.

*There are no people here.*

Plural. Same as in English.

> Hier ist keiner.

*There is no one here.*

And again, singular. Same as in English.

Comment: Ich glaube, die Frage des Fragestellers war falsch gestellt: Er wollte nicht wissen, wie "keiner" konjugiert wird, sondern wie das Verb konjugiert wird, wenn das Subjekt des Satztes "keiner" ist.

Comment: Genau darauf wollte ich hinaus: "1. Person oder 3. Person" ergibt in diesem Zusammenhang keinen Sinn. Es geht hier ausschließlich um Singular oder Plural. Und diese Entscheidung fällt im Deutschen, wie ich unten schrieb, genau wie im Englischen. Die akzeptierte Antwort erwähnt "kein" als Subjekt, allerdings hat der Fragesteller dieses Subjekt nicht, sondern "keiner von beiden" (und es ist auch nicht "3. Person", sondern einfach das Subjekt), und die Antwort verwendet dieses Beispiel auch nicht, aber ich werde diese Antwort natürlich dennoch **nicht** downvoten, denn mir ist das zu doof.